# Copy Text from textview With Custom font in iPhone

Tags: email, copy, message, custom-font

I am using custom font in app. And I want to copy text from text with its font style and want to paste it to paste it in another app or add that text to mail/message with its font style that I applied in my app.

I am using following code for copy:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    pasteboard.string = self.text_view.text;
```

And for mail:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"From Font app"]; 
    [controller setMessageBody:self.text_view.text isHTML:NO];
    if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And for message:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.body = self.text_view.text;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But it copy/add text only default font.

How can I also copy custom font with it?